# Displaying Direction on Map in iOS MapKit

Tags: ios, google-maps, dictionary, mapkit, direction

I am new into using MapKit in iOS. I would like to display an arrow image on the route joining two points in iOS MapKit. I am able to place the arrow's image as an annotation pin at any point in the route, but I am not able to orient it properly. How can I orient the arrow properly to point properly.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to join two points on the map you will want to use an overlay ([`MKOverlay`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/MapKit/Reference/MKOverlay_protocol/Reference/Reference.html)) rather than an annotation. Annotations are used as map markers for single points.

If you just want to have an arrow over one point that points towards the other point you could do that by subclassing `MKAnnotation` and `MKAnnotationView`. In your subclassed `MKAnnotation`, add an extra property of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D` that defines where your arrow will point towards. Then, in the `MKAnnotationView` use the two coordinates to work out the direction of your arrow and adjust the image accordingly.